# Counting Sort List of Integers in C

Tags: c, sorting, integer, counting

I am trying to create a program that will Counting Sort a randomly generated list of integers. I want to generate a list of say 3000 integers, take half of them and sort. Then I want to take the sorted integers that I just sorted and save them into a temporary file. I then want to take the other half of integers and sort them as well and save them into a different temp file. Once both halves are sorted I want to merge both temporary files into one file.

My question is how do I generate the random 3000 integers and save them to a temporary file and then call them into my counting sort function?

Here is some of my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void counting_sort_mm(int *array, int n, int min, int max)
{
  int i, j, z;

  int range = max - min + 1;
  int *count = malloc(range * sizeof(*array));

  for(i = 0; i < range; i++) count[i] = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) count[ array[i] - min ]++;

  for(i = min, z = 0; i <= max; i++) 
  {
    for(j = 0; j < count[i - min]; j++) 
    {
      array[z++] = i;
    }
  } 

  free(count);
}

void counting_sort(int *array, int n)
{
  int i, min, max;

  min = max = array[0];
  for(i=1; i < n; i++) 
  {
    if ( array[i] < min ) 
    {
      min = array[i];
    } else if ( array[i] > max ) 
    {
      max = array[i];
    }
  }
}
```

---

My Random Generator (still not sure how to save them into two different temp files..)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int c, n;

  for (c = 1; c <= 3000; c++) {
    n = rand()%100 + 1;
    printf("%d\n", n);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you know the range of the random numbers?

Comment: I just want 0 to 3000 integers with the size no bigger than 10,000

Comment: I didn't give you this -1, but unlike the person who did I think I can explain why it happened, derk.  For this question, we really want to see the code you are trying to write to generate the random numbers, the sorting code is tangential.  Keep your question and it's example code focused on the problem, and you will get better results here.  Start by writing some code that calls rand().

Comment: You need to put the numbers in an array, sort them, then use `fopen` `fprintf` `fclose` to store the sorted array in a file. You can then `fopen` `fscanf` to read from the file, and `fclose` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating the files for `array_1` and `array_2` is fairly straight forward. You can likewise limit the `max` values for the numbers generated to whatever you like with the `% modulo` operator. The following is a small example with comments explaining the approach. The following routine will prompt the user for the total number of elements to split between two files. (if odd, the second array will be one bigger than the first). In your case, entering `3000` will cause two arrays to be created of `1500` elements each with values between `1 - 10000` saved in `array_1.txt` and `array_2.txt` in the current working directory.

You can change the range of the numbers generated simple by changing the `#define AMAX 10000` definition at the beginning. A valid range is `0 - INT_MAX`. Let me know if you have any questions. Start a second question when you get to the `mergesort` part of the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define AMAX 10000

int main () {

    int n = 0;              /* total number of elements for arrays  */
    int *array_1 = NULL;    /* array to hold 1/2 total elements     */
    int *array_2 = NULL;    /* array to hold 1/2 total elements     */
    int sz_1 = 0;           /* size of array_1 array (1/2 * n)      */
    int sz_2 = 0;           /* size of array_2 (n - sz_1) +1 if odd */
    int i = 0;              /* general iterator                     */
    FILE *ofp = NULL;       /* file stream pointer                  */

    printf ("\nEnter the total number of elements to be split between 2 arrays : ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);

    sz_1 = n / 2;                                   /* compute sz_1                         */
    sz_2 = n - sz_1;                                /* compute sz_2 (handle odd 'n')        */

    array_1 = calloc (sz_1, sizeof (int));          /* allocate mem for array_1 init to 0   */
    array_2 = calloc (sz_2, sizeof (int));          /* allocate mem for array_2 init to 0   */

    srand (time(NULL));                             /* seed psuedo-random number sequence   */

    if (!(ofp = fopen ("array_1.txt", "w")))        /* open file for array_1 values         */
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to open output file 'array_1.txt'\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sz_1; i++)                      /* fill array_1 with random values      */
    {
        array_1[i] = (rand() % AMAX) + 1;           /* semi-random No. between 1 - AMAX     */
        fprintf (ofp, "%d\n", array_1[i]);          /* write to file array_1.txt            */
    }

    fclose (ofp);                                   /* close array_1 file stream            */

    if (!(ofp = fopen ("array_2.txt", "w")))        /* open file for array_2 values         */
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to open output file 'array_2.txt'\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sz_2; i++)                      /* fill array_2 with random values      */
    {
        array_2[i] = (rand() % AMAX) + 1;           /* semi-random No. between 1 - AMAX     */
        fprintf (ofp, "%d\n", array_2[i]);          /* write to file array_2.txt            */
    }

    fclose (ofp);                                   /* close array_2 file stream            */

    /* do what ever else you need to do with array_1/array_2 (you can sort before save )*/

    if (array_1) free (array_1);                    /* free memory allocated to array       */
    if (array_2) free (array_2);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example - use and output:**

```
$ ./bin/tworanda

Enter the total number of elements to be split between 2 arrays : 20

$ cat array_1.txt
4585
3295
4702
2030
5816
6157
7130
6913
3285
5811

$ cat array_2.txt
9926
8967
1103
5704
3964
207
8460
8387
2665
8094
```